# How does dom4j handle <import>?

Tags: xml, import, dom4j

I need to import an XML file into another XML file. I know there is an  tag I can use, but I need to know how dom4j handles this.

Does it import it and act like its part of the file, or does it do anything at all?

If it doesn't do anything at all, how can I use the tag to import an XML file?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no pre defined XML tag to import another XML file, DOM4J cannot handle it. You might be referring to "external entities", as discussed for example [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tipgentity/).

In the "external entities" case, it is not DOM4J that resolves the references, but rather the SAX parser used for XML parsing.